# Image Logo positioned differently between mobile devices and browser

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

I have a problem with my CSS logo positioning.
My site is : http://www.askjansen.co.cc
The problem is, when I opened it with my browser (like chrome, safari, etc) and smartphone browser (iPhone) the header logo is fine.  But if I opened it with my blackberry browser, the image is not aligned well.

Below is my HTML syntax :

```
<h1 class="logo" id="image-logo">       
    <a style="background:url(http://askjansen.co.cc/wp-content/themes/Weekly/images/logo.png) no-repeat" href="http://askjansen.co.cc" title="Ask Jansen" rel="home">Ask Jansen <span class="desc">Good Nutrition is a Start</span></a>

    </h1>
```

And this is my CSS syntax :

```
    ![.logo {
    float: left;
}

.logo {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.logo a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
}

.logo a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.logo .desc {
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial,serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #aaa;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
}

.logo a:hover .desc {
    color: #aaa;
}

#text-logo a {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

#image-logo {
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#image-logo a {
    position:absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 90px;
    text-indent: -5555em;
    overflow: hidden;
}][1]
```

Below is the picture from blackberry's browser (notice the different position on the logo) :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVdaG.jpg

How to solve this?  Thank You!

Comment: It's not clear what "different position" means, and you're going to drive yourself insane if you try to get your website to look identical on every mobile browser.

Comment: Do you have to use `<h1>` to wrap the image? Otherwise why don´t you put it (as an `<img>`) into the already existing `<div id="header">` - there you can position it via margins / paddings: `header img { margin: //whatever; padding: // whatever; }` Anyway, i don´t know much about wordpress...

Comment: so there's no way to make it all look the same on all kind of browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at it right now and it's off on every browser I try it on: Firefox, Safari, IE.

Change your #image-logo a top style to 60px rather than 80px

Comment: I've tried change it to 60 px and it fit on the blackberry's browser but then the looks on chrome and iOS's safari would be upscaled too.

Answer (score 0):

You could really optimize and clean your code, this will reduce (in theory) the occurrence of bugs.

It's more correct to set the logo as `<img>` tag instead of `<h1>`, because logo is content, not style.

The **HTML**:

```
<a href="./" class="logo">
    <img src="path/to/logo.png" alt="Ask Jansen, Good nutrition is a Start" width="300" height="90">
</a>
```

The **CSS**:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0; }
.logo img {
    display: block; }
```

More information about logo as h1 or image: http://csswizardry.com/2010/10/your-logo-is-an-image-not-a-h1/

Hope this helps.

## Quick Fix

Have you tried remove the `margin: 20px 0 0 0;` and add its value on the `top: 80px;` (60px + 20px)?